# How can I make a "squishy slide" animation in React / MUI?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, material-ui, css-transitions

I have a list of items. When I first load the page, I want them to slide in sequentially in rapid succession and then shrink slightly when they arrive at their final destination -- sort of like what would happen if you dropped a stack of pillows, or maybe [a giant stack of sliced deli meat](https://youtu.be/3spQjln9fgg). (I've seen this animation in the past but I can't find an example and I have no idea what it's called; if anyone can find a link to an example, please post it.)

Here's my highly rudimentary attempt:

```
import {Button, Slide, Stack, StackProps} from '@mui/material'
import {Box} from '@mui/system'

interface ZoomStackProps extends PropsWithChildren<StackProps> {
    timeout: number
}

export default function SquishSlideStack({children, timeout, ...stackProps}: ZoomStackProps) {

    const [mountIndex,   setMountIndex] = useState(0)
    const [squozeIndex, setSquozeIndex] = useState(0)

    function increment(n: number) {
        if (n < React.Children.count(children) - 1) {
            setMountIndex(n)
            setTimeout(() => increment(n + 1), timeout)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => increment(1), [])

    return (
        <Stack {...stackProps}>
            <Button onClick={() => setMountIndex(index => index + 1)}>Next</Button>
            {React.Children.map(children, (child, i) =>
                i > mountIndex ? (
                    null
                ) : (
                    <Slide
                        key={i}
                        in={true}
                        direction='up'
                        timeout={1000}
                        addEndListener={() => setSquozeIndex(i)}
                    >
                        <Box bgcolor='green'
                             width={600}
                             height={50}
                             sx={{
                                  transform: i > squozeIndex ? 'scale(1, 1.5)' : 'scale(1, 1)',
                                  transition: 'transform 2s ease'
                             }}
                        >
                            {child}
                        </Box>
                    </Slide>
                )
            )}
        </Stack>
    )
}
```

See [Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-pond-jo7pox).

The sliding part here works, more or less, but only when I leave the squishing/scaling part off. Adding that breaks sliding and also doesn't scale correctly, for some reason.

What's the best way to achieve an animation like this in React (and hopefully in MUI, though that's not required)?

Comment: I've been thinking about your question for a few days.  It is a fascinating problem.  I'm not quite sure how to do it, but I think my direction would be to use the react-spring library.  I think it could inject some styles into a custom MUI component that you could then use to get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement is CSS3 animation.

If you want any help about implementation in React and MUI, please comment.

A simple Demo here, you may need to change parameter about **translate3d** and **scaleY** in animation as you like.

```html
<h1 class="callout-title_first animate__animated">Animate.css</h1>
<h1 class="callout-title_bottom animate__animated">Animate.css</h1>
<style>
  h1 {
    margin:0;
  }

  @keyframes slideInDown_first {
  0%{
    transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
  }
  33%{
    transform: translate3d(0,50%,0) ;
  }
  40%{
    transform-origin: bottom;;
    transform: translate3d(0,50%,0) scaleY(0.5);
  }
  to{
      transform: scaleY(0.5) translate3d(0,100%,0);
  }
}

  @keyframes slideInDown_second {
  0%{
    transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
  }
  33%{
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0) ;
  }
  40%{
    transform-origin: bottom;;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scaleY(0.5);
  }
  66%{
    transform: translate3d(0,-20%,0) scaleY(0.5);
  }
  to{
      transform: translateZ(0);
      transform: scaleY(0.5);
  }
}
.animate__slideInDown_first {
  animation-name: slideInDown_first
}
.animate__slideInDown_second {
  animation-name: slideInDown_second
}
.animate__animated {
    animation-duration: 3000ms;
    animation-fill-mode: both
}
</style>
<script>
  document.querySelector('.callout-title_first').classList.add('animate__slideInDown_first')
  document.querySelector('.callout-title_bottom').classList.add('animate__slideInDown_second')
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks YinPeng -- I'm hoping to leverage MUI or React animations rather than defining keyframes -- but if I have to use keyframes, that's fine. However, a larger problem is that the list of items I want to animate is dynamic (not a fixed size) and probably large. So I can't define a separate style for each item like this (`_first` and `_second`); I need a solution that would work with any number of items.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I would use the CSS animations :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Stack } from '@mui/material';
import { styled } from '@mui/system';

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 50;

const Wrapper = styled('div')({
  position: 'relative',
  overflow: 'hidden',
  height: ITEM_HEIGHT * 3,
});

const Item = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  position: 'absolute',
  width: '100%',
  height: ITEM_HEIGHT,
  background: 'green',
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  fontSize: 24,
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  color: theme.palette.common.white,
  animation: 'slideIn 0.3s ease-out forwards, squish 0.3s ease-out forwards',
  animationDelay: '0.1s',
  transformOrigin: 'center bottom',
}));

const SquishSlideStack = ({ children }) => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(-1);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timer;
    if (index < children.length - 1) {
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setIndex((i) => i + 1);
      }, 200);
    }
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [index, children]);

  return (
    <Stack>
      <Wrapper>
        {children.map((child, i) => (
          <Item
            key={i}
            style={{
              top: ITEM_HEIGHT * i,
              animationDelay: `${i * 0.1}s`,
              transform: `scale(${index === i ? '1,1.5' : '1,1'})`,
            }}
          >
            {child}
          </Item>
        ))}
      </Wrapper>
      <Button disabled={index >= children.length - 1} onClick={() => setIndex((i) => i + 1)}>
        Next
      </Button>
    </Stack>
  );
};
```